# Lambda initialization and validation error Lex

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, chatbot, amazon-lex

I want to branch an intent in Amazon Lex for which I set up a Lambda function with ElicitSlot as per the documentation.
However, whenever the function is supposed to be initialized - even when there's no executable code or just a log output - I get this error as follows:

> An error has occurred: The server encountered an error processing the
> Lambda response

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong... Do I need to allow some permission for the lambda, perhaps or create a VPC or something?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: To me it sounds that there is something wrong with the result that is returned by the Lambda, if that is even possible. Would you be able to post Lambda code, omtting any sensitive values if any?

Comment: @MarkoE Nah, I tried to comment everything out from the Lambda code. Must be something else...

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Lex will return this response when the Lambda function called throws an error or returns an invalid or incorrectly formatted response.

If you can, please share the relevant snippet of code that returns the response to Lex.

Have you checked your CloudWatch logs to see if the Lambda function is logging any errors?